# Is this NaNNaNNaN error caused by concatenation or something else?

Tags: javascript

When creating a HTML table using javascript it ends up showing "NaNNaNNaN" next to the table

> **NaNNaNNaN form the .innerHTML using html tag inside the script**

multipe objects in the .innerHTML

Here's code:

```js
 // Constructor function for Person objects
    function Person(first, last, relation, gender, age, eye) {
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
      this.relation = relation;
      this.gender = gender;
      this.age = age;
      this.eyeColor = eye;
    }
    // Create 2 Person objects
    const myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", "father", "Male", 50, "Blue");
    const myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally","mother", "Female", 48, "Green");
    // Add a name method to first object
    myMother.name = function() {
      return "<table border= '2' align='center'>"+
      "<tr>"+
      "<th>"+"First Name"+"</th>"+
      "<th>"+"Last Name"+"</th>"+
      "<th>"+"Age"+"</th>"+
      "<th>"+"Relation"+"</th>"+
      "<th>"+"Gender"+"</th>"+
      "<th>"+"Eye Color"+"</th>"+
      +"</tr>"+
      "<tr>"+
      "<td>"+this.firstName+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+this.lastName+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+this.age+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+this.relation+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+this.gender+"</td>"+
    
      "<td>"+this.eyeColor+"</td>"+
      +"</tr>"+
      +"</table>"
      };
    // Display full name
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
    myMother.name();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Object Constructors</h2>
    <p id="demo">
    </p> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

***here's output***
[image]

Comment: You have sequences of two `+` signs. For example: `"<th>"+"Eye Color"+"</th>"+` and on the next line `+"</tr>"+` - remove those multiple pluses between the two lines. Only have one `+` between strings you want to concatenate. Or use a template literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos (too many + +). But you really want something like this

Why only have a table row function for the mother?

```js
function Person(first, last, relation, gender, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.relation = relation;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
  this.name = () => `
    <tr>
      <td>${this.firstName}</td>
      <td>${this.lastName}</td>
      <td>${this.age}</td>
      <td>${this.relation}</td>
      <td>${this.gender}</td>
      <td>${this.eyeColor}</td>
    </tr>`;
};

// Create 2 Person objects
const myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", "father", "Male", 50, "Blue");
const myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", "mother", "Female", 48, "Green");
// Display full name
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myMother.name();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myFather.name();
```

```css
thead
```

```html
<table border='2' align='center'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Relation</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Eye Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While a big improvement to the code, it is not an answer to the question of where the mysterious triple NaN comes from. And you might as well have used the prototype for adding a method instead of creating inner closures, when push comes to show ;)

Comment: @swastha See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: The "mysterious NaN" is because they have three duplicate `+` operators.

Comment: [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) You forgot to write **Age** in the third `<th>` .

Answer (score 1):

As mplungjan says, you have too many plus signs, but here is what is happening and why:

When you have this snippet, the result is `</tr>NaN`.

```js
console.log("</tr>"+      +"</table>" )
```

Why? Because of forced type coercion. The extra plus sign forces numeric conversion of a string, so `"</table>"` becomes a number. An invalid number in this case (NaN = Not a Number).

```
1 + "1"
> '11'
1 + +"1"
> 2
1 + + "not a number"
> NaN
"a string" + + "not a number"
> 'a stringNaN'
```

So why does the table still render? Because of a permissive DOM rendering model. If some nodes are missing the browser will still try to render the resulting DOM nodes, completing missing end tags as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your updated code. I'm using `Template Literals` syntax. Learn more about [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here. I've minimized your code so that you can add new `rows` in the table instead of repeating the whole table for each new entry.

```js
function Person(first, last, relation, gender, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.relation = relation;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
  this.name = () => `
    <tr>
      <td>${this.firstName}</td>
      <td>${this.lastName}</td>
      <td>${this.age}</td>
      <td>${this.relation}</td>
      <td>${this.gender}</td>
      <td>${this.eyeColor}</td>
    </tr>`;
};

// Create 2 Person objects
const myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", "Father", "Male", 50, "Blue");
const myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", "Mother", "Female", 48, "Green");
const myBrother = new Person("Alex", "Doe", "Brother", "Male", 48, "Black");
// Display full name
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myMother.name();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myFather.name();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myBrother.name();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>JavaScript Object Constructors</h2>
  <table border='2' align='center'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Relation</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Eye Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have posted a verbatim copy of my code with just a person added and the `Age` I forgot. It is plagiarism and against SO guidelines

Comment: NO Bro. I had already written the answer but my answer was uploaded late due to an interrupt in internet connectivity. I never theft anyone's answers or copy/paste them, or use plagiarised content. Still, if you think I did that so, what I can do is delete my answer. 

Answer (score 0):

permit me to Add... why not use interpolation with Template Literals on your variables, utilization of back ticks...

```
`<td> ${this.firstName} </td>
 <td> ${this.lastName} </td>`
```

its going to save you a lot of stress, and you can get rid of the + concatenation signs.

Comment: While a good tip to improve the code, it is best left as a comment as this does not serve as an answer to the question.